# Javascript class change for altering CSS not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am learning javascript. I have made a tab menu by learning and following the code instructions on the following linked webpage: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

The only difference in my code is that instead of the buttons, i have used links.
Problem: The 'active' class CSS dosen't affect the active tab permanently during its life. I see it affecting for a second and then it is gone... back to its non active properties.

Why is this happening and what should be done?

My Code:

```
function select(x, post/*id-->qpost*/) {
            // Declare all variables
            var i, tabcontent, tablink;

            // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "selected"
            tablink = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
            for (i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
            tablink[i].className = tablink[i].className.replace(" selected", "");
            }

            // Show the current tab, and add an "selected" class to the button that opened the tab
            document.getElementById(post).classList.remove("tabcontent");
            x.currentTarget.className += " selected";
            }
```

CSS

```
section#cat_list a.selected{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
}
article#qpost{
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="./welcome.php?cat=1" class="tablink" id="primary_cat" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">NEW</a>
    <a href="./welcome.php?cat=2" class="tablink" id="primary_cat" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">TOP RATED</a>
    <a href="./welcome.php?cat=3" class="tablink" id="primary_cat" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">RANDOM</a>
<a id="primary_cat" class="tablink" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">ALL CATEGORIES</a><!--The active class change works perfectly here (this link has no href)-->
<article id='qpost' class='tabcontent'><!--...--></article>
```

Comment: show your code....

Comment: Please add your code in the question whatever you tried.

Comment: Your code may be refreshing the page when you click the anchor tabs, so you might be seeing the code working for a second before your browser reloads, but that can't be confirmed without seeing the code

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Here is my code...

Comment: @Bhansa Code...

Comment: @PatrickBarr Code... Hey...is my php GET refreshing the page?

Comment: @user7704928 I'm fairly confident that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, it looks like the JS is being reloaded.

You could get the `cat=#` value from the url using [this function](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/) and call the `select()` after the page loads with the `onLoad` attribute.

I didn't test this code, though this should be along the lines of what you're looking for.

JS

```
// https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}

function select(x, post/*id-->qpost*/) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablink;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "selected"
    tablink = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
        tablink[i].className = tablink[i].className.replace(" selected", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "selected" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(post).classList.remove("tabcontent");
    // utilizing javascript's nifty truthy-ness to check if x is null
    if(x) x.currentTarget.className += " selected";
    else {
        document.getElementById('primary_cat_' + getQueryVariable("cat")).className += " selected";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body onLoad="select(null, 'qpost')">
  <a href="./welcome.php?cat=1" class="tablink" id="primary_cat_1" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">NEW</a>
  <a href="./welcome.php?cat=2" class="tablink" id="primary_cat_2" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">TOP RATED</a>
  <a href="./welcome.php?cat=3" class="tablink" id="primary_cat_3" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">RANDOM</a>
  <a id="primary_cat" class="tablink" onclick="select(event, 'qpost')">ALL CATEGORIES</a><!--The active class change works perfectly here (this link has no href)-->
  <article id='qpost' class='tabcontent'><!--...--></article>
</body>
```

Comment: @user7704928 I added the code, I didn't test it, though it should be very close to what you're looking for if it doesn't work, I didn't put an id on that last one because I don't believe it redirects because it doesn't have an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you have duplicate `id` references. You can only use them once in your HTML. Either change them to classes or give each id a unique name

Comment: This is a problem, though the code never explicitly uses those id's to reference the anchors. Also the events would have a reference to the DOM element giving another way to access it without an id.